# Labels not showing on CoCA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, label

I have preformed a CoCA in R following [R CCA only displaying 4 vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041924/r-cca-only-displaying-4-vectors), but I keep receiving one graph without any labels. I used the cocorresp package.

[none labelled CoCA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIKCk.png)

Here is my code:

```
#making a data frame
snails <- data.frame(snails)
plants <- data.frame(plants)

#adding rownames and removing the first row
sites <- plants [,1]
plants <- plants [,-1]
snails <- snails [,-1]

rownames(plants) <-sites
rownames(snails) <- sites

## log transform
snaillog<- log1p(snails)
## fit the model
sp.sym <- coca(snaillog ~ ., data = plants, method = "predictive")
sp.sym

#plotting graph
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
plot(sp.sym, which = "response", main = "Snails")
plot(sp.sym, which = "predictor", main = "Plants")
layout(1)
```

Any ideas to why my predicting variables has no labels? There are about 82 columns for my `plants` and 27 columns for `snails`. I have tried sites `<- snails [,1]` (as a reserve). They are at the same sites so I believe that doesn't matter.